# How to implement Log base 2 in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, math, calculator, calculation

How can I find Log2(x) in flutter?

I didn't found the match function in flutter math package

Note:

Log base 2

Comment: Use the logarithm change of base formula.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm#Change_of_base

Answer (score 3):

As the others said, you can use the [Logarithm change of base formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm#Change_of_base)
.

```
import 'dart:math';

double logBase(num x, num base) => log(x) / log(base);
double log2(num x) => logBase(x, 2);
```

Answer (score 1):

As others mentioned, implementing log base X is a one-liner, but if you'd rather someone else write that one line, then take a look at the [Dart Basic Utils](https://pub.dev/packages/basic_utils) package which has this implemented. Specifically, see the MathUtils section: https://github.com/Ephenodrom/Dart-Basic-Utils#mathutils

Disclaimer: I'm the one who contributed said functionality.